# Agregar a una misma línea/fila de un datagridview información capturada de un dataview, combobox y textbox

Tags: formularios, datagridview

Soy nueva en programando en c#, después de 10 años de haber dejado de lado la programación he retomado. Tengo un proyecto, el que llevo bastante adelantado; sin embargo, en una de las formas al momento de ASIGAR MATERIAL estoy atascada porque estoy utilizando dos dataview.
Uno de ellos, ya lo relleno adecuadamente con la información validada. El problema lo tengo en el segundo dataview. Es una estructura de producto un poco complicada. En el primer dataview (DVG_capa), se define un producto principal el cual tiene SOLO tres capas A, B, C y cada una tiene un porcentaje asociado (este funciona ok) Para el segundo dataview, en el que tengo problemas (DGV_Material- con columnas definidas IdCapa, mat1, Porc1 ...mat4, porc4) previamente debo seleccionar una de las capas del dataview anterior y por cada capa debo escoger entre 1 hasta 4 materiales diferentes cada uno con su respectivo porcentaje. Por ejemplo, al escoger la primera capa A (en el primer dataview: DGV_capa), indico en el combobox (DGV_NumMat) el número de materiales que tendrá esa capa, en el siguiente combobox (Cb_idmaterial) debo seleccionar el primer material, asignar un porcentaje (txt_PorcMat) y meterlo en una fila y en ESA MISMA FILA debo agregar el segundo material y su porcentaje y así sucesivamente hasta completar la cantidad de materiales escogido en el numero de materiales. Y esto mismo se debe hacer con la CAPA B y C.

Paso el código del primer dataview. La imagen del formulario, aunque sea con el fallo que estoy teniendo en el segundo dataview. El código del segundo dataview, he borrado todos mis intentos para empezar de ceros. Gracias de antemano y espero alguien me pueda ilustrar con alguna de idea de como iniciar la programación de este segundo dataview. GRACIAS.[image: Formulario Estructura]

```
private void Btn_AsignaCapa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Valida que Capa y tipo capa no este repetido en el DataView
        if (DGV_Capa.RowCount > 0)
        {
            // Primero averigua si el registro existe:
            for (int i = 0; i < DGV_Capa.RowCount; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(DGV_Capa.Rows[i].Cells["Capa"].Value) == CB_Capa.Text || (Convert.ToString(DGV_Capa.Rows[i].Cells["TipoCapa"].Value) == CB_TpCapa.Text))
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show("La capa o tipo de capa ya existe", "Registro duplicado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error) == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }               
        }

        int acumporccapa = 0;
        int sumacapa = 0;
        int ultimacapa = 0;
        if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(Txt_PpalDesMat.Text)) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(CB_Capa.Text)) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(CB_TpCapa.Text)) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Txt_PorcCapa.Text)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Debe introducir todos los datos de la nueva estructura. Inténtelo de nuevo");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //Controla que la suma de las capas sume 100%
            sumacapa = SumarPorcCapa();
            acumporccapa = sumacapa + Convert.ToInt32(Txt_PorcCapa.Text);

            if (acumporccapa <= 100)
            {
                if (this.lonDatageid == 2)
                {
                    if (acumporccapa == 100)
                    {
                        DGV_Capa.Rows.Add(CB_Capa.Text, CB_TpCapa.Text, Txt_PorcCapa.Text);
                        CB_Capa.SelectedIndex = -1;
                        CB_TpCapa.SelectedIndex = -1;
                        Txt_PorcCapa.Text = "";
                        CB_Capa.Focus();
                        LB_Suma.Text = acumporccapa.ToString();
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("La suma de los porcentajes de la capa no pueden exceder el 100%");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DGV_Capa.Rows.Add(CB_Capa.Text, CB_TpCapa.Text, Txt_PorcCapa.Text);
                    CB_Capa.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    CB_TpCapa.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    Txt_PorcCapa.Text = "";
                    CB_Capa.Focus();
                    LB_Suma.Text = acumporccapa.ToString();
                    return;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("La suma de los porcentajes de la capa no pueden exceder el 100%");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

   public int SumarPorcCapa()
    {
        lonDatageid = 0;
        int totalcapa = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in DGV_Capa.Rows)
        {
            totalcapa += Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells["PorcCapa"].Value);
            lonDatageid = lonDatageid + 1;
        }

        return totalcapa;
    }
```